# When does $f = gh$ with $f,g$ smooth imply that $h$ is smooth?

Tags: derivatives, smooth-functions

Let $f,g,h$ be three real-valued functions on an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ such that
$$f = gh.$$

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are smooth, i.e., infinitely differentiable. **Under what conditions does this imply that $h$ is smooth?**

The following counterexample
$$f(x) = x,\qquad g(x) = x^2,\qquad h(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}1/x &x\neq 0\\
0 &x=0\end{matrix}\right.$$
show that this is not necessarily true. On the other hand, $g$ being is nowhere vanishing would be a sufficient condition since in that case we could write $h = f/g$.

Is there anything interesting to say in between?

Comment: Perhaps if all three are continuous then the statement holds?

Comment: $h=f/g$ when $g(x)\neq 0$. So, I guess the smoothness of $h$ depend on zeros of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Roughly speaking, zeros of $f$ must 'cancel out' those of $g$. If you don't want any such condition on $f$, then you cannot relax the hypothesis that $g$ has no zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's much of an in between: Already if $g$ has just one root, then $h$ doesn't have to be smooth anymore. For example, consider $g=f=\text{id}_{\mathbb{R^n}}$ and $h=1_{\mathbb{R^n}}-1_{\{0\}}$. Then $f,g$ are smooth and $f=gh$ but $h$ is obviously not even differentiable.